# Getting hierarchy level of yaml parameter

Tags: ros, yaml, rosparam, parameter, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use ros param to traverse files like this:

```
pcl_filter:
  filter:
    filter_cascade_1: 
      in:  cloud_in
      out: cloud_out
      filter:
        first_applied_filter:
          - config_for_filter_1
          - config_for_filter_2
        second_applied_filter:
          - config_for_filter_1
          - config_for_filter_2
    filter_cascade_2:
      in:  other_cloud_in
      out: other_cloud_out
      filter:
        first_applied_filter:
          - config_for_filter_1
          - config_for_filter_2
        second_applied_filter:
          - config_for_filter_1
          - config_for_filter_2
```

There I would like to get all cascades of the param "filter". In the node pcl_filter I search for something like

```
std::vector<std::string> param;
getParam("filter", param);
```

But this just seems to work with something like:

```
pcl_filter:
  filter:
    - filter_cascade_1
    - filter_cascade_1
```

And:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> param;
getParam("filter", param);
```

just workes with:

```
pcl_filter:
  filter:
    filter_cascade_1: a
    filter_cascade_1: b
```

Does somebody know a way to get all of these parameter?

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189299/getting-hierarchy-level-of-yaml-parameter/) by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just did this for one of my packages. Here is some example code:

```
#include <XmlRpcValue.h>
...

void my_node::parseParams(ros::NodeHandle n) {
  XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue filters;
  n.getParam("filter", filters);
  ROS_ASSERT(filters.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeStruct);
  for(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::ValueStruct::const_iterator it = filters.begin(); it != filters.end(); ++it) {
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Found filter: " << (std::string)(it->first) << " ==> " << filters[it->first]);
    // Do stuff with filters:
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("filter_cascade_1: in: " << filters[it->first]["in"]);
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("filter_cascade_1: filter: first_applied_filter: config_for_filter_1: " << filters[it->first]["filter"]["first_applied_filter"][0]);
  }
}
```

This works with xmlrpc structs which is what you get when you query arbitrary parameter namespaces. The iterator contains as `it->first` the keys of all the parameters found in the `filter` namespace: `filter_cascade_1` and `filter_cascade_2` and the `it->second` contains a xmlrpc struct of the parameters in that namespace. It is not really nice or convenient to use but I hope the example helps a bit.

Edit: Just to elaborate a bit more, the `XmlRpcValue::TypeStruct` is just a `std::map<std::string,XmlRpcValue::TypeStruct>`. If you look at the output of this line `ROS_INFO_STREAM("Found filter: " << (std::string)(it->first) << " ==> " << filters[it->first]);` it should be quite clear how to use it I hope. Took me a few hours to find the right way of doing this so if you have any problems, just let me know.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thank you very much, this is what I needed :)
Unfortunately there is no ´std::mapstd::string,XmlRpcValue::TypeStruct´, that would produce much better code to read, but your solution works just as intended

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2014-08-07**:
You're welcome. I know it's a bit messy... The python interface for this is much better I have to admit but sometimes you just can't avoid using some C++ as well :(